# Error when displaying multiple map locations in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps

I'm trying to display multiple locations in google map using their latitude and longitude from database.

This is my code :

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
<script>
function initMap() 
{
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(50);
    var markers = [['<?php echo $vendor_name; ?>', '<?php echo $vendor_latitude; ?>', '<?php echo $vendor_longitude; ?>']];
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<?php echo $vendor_name; ?>' + '</div>']];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });   
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });   
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

```html
<div id="mapCanvas" name="mapCanvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

This map is supposed to show multiple restaurants using their latitude and longitude from database. But the problem here is that I'm able to display only the restaurant which was added last in the database.

Can someone please help me display all the restaurants in the map?

Comment: First of all, how was the restaurants data formatted? what's the variable storing it?

Comment: Can you share the var_dump of $vendor_name, $vendor_latitude, $vendor_longitude

Answer (score 0):

Inside the initMap() function, you can store all your restaurant locations in a single array first:

```
        ///populate this array with your list of restaurants
        ///sample content
        var vendorList = [
                ['vendor 1', '51.493225','-0.184325'],
                ['vendor 2', '51.498970','-0.186340'],
                ['vendor 3', '51.487782','-0.2027224']
        ];
```

And then loop through that list to display the markers:

```
        ///loop through the declared array
        for( i = 0; i < vendorList.length; i++ ) { ..... }
```

Check out this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bv1xmrtk/4/) that's recreated from your given code and displays 3 markers for all three sample vendor locations.
[image: sample with 3 markers]

Hope this helps!